# How to delete the corresponding MKAnnotation when a row in tableview is deleted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkannotation

My program will add 1 drop pin (showing coord, speed, and time stamp) to the map after user has moved a certain distance. At the same time adding the pin, it'll also add the corresponding coordinate to the UITableView.

This is part of the code in G5MapViewController.m

```
G5MapPoint *mp = [[G5MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord title:@"Your Trail" speed:resultStr];

[worldView addAnnotation:mp];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 300, 300);
[worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];

float latitude = coord.latitude;
float longitude = coord.longitude;
count += 1;

NSString *coordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %f, %f", count, latitude, longitude];
G5SharedStore *store = [G5SharedStore sharedStore];
//Create an NSMutableArray
[[G5SharedStore sharedStore]create:coordString];
```

This is part of the code in G5MapPoint.m

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t speed:(NSString *)s
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        coordinate = c;
        [self setTitle:t];

        /*NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        [self setSubtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]]];*/

        [self setSubtitle:s];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And this is my G5DetailViewController

```
    G5SharedStore *store = [G5SharedStore sharedStore];
    //Determine the last row in the array
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:store.allCoords.count inSection:0];
    //Insert row into the table
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@" UITableViewCell"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Now, when I delete a row with coordinate in the tableView, I want it to also delete the corresponding drop pin connected with that row. I was thinking of comparing timestamp and deleting the pin with timestamp similar to the one in the row, but not sure if that's a good method to do. Anyone have any suggestion to work around this problem? Thanks guys

Comment: Put your annotations into an NSMutableArray where the index is the same as the row index.  When you delete a row you can simply remove the corresponding annotation from the map and the delete it from the array

Comment: Also you don't need to call `registerClass` each time- only once in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: So that means, I'll have to add the annotations into an array first, then add them to the map from the array. Which will enable me to delete them by accessing the array?

Comment: And how would I go about deleting the annotation from the map? If I use [mapView removeAnnotation:[self.annotationArray objectAtIndex:index]]; I get this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString setRowIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1cc680'" Please guide me ...

Comment: That exception means that you have called the `setRowIndex` method on a NSString.  What did you put in the array?  Please update your question to show your new code